# Send TextField values (parameter) to a servlet

Tags: java, sql, servlets, portlet, vaadin

i have 3 TextFields (Vaadin) ( DBName, DBUserName, DBPassword) i want to send the typed in text from a portlet to a servlet , this is what i've got so far :

Portlet part:

```
TextField DBName;
TextField DBUserName;
TextField DBPassword;

DBName = new TextField("Enter DB Name");
DBName.setColumns(20);
DBUserName = new TextField("Enter UserName");
DBUserName.setColumns(20);
DBPassword = new TextField("Enter Password");
DBPassword.setColumns(20);
     //Button
    if(event.getSource()== Connect){
        Resource newPictureResource = new ExternalResource("http://localhost:8888/portlet/picture?UserName="+DBUserName.getValue()+"&DBPassword="+DBPassword.getValue()+"&DBName="+DBName.getValue());
        picture.setSource(newPictureResource);
        editContent.addComponent(picture);
    }
```

Servlet part :

no ideas here , was thinkig about

```
    String UserName = request.getParameter("DBUserName");
    String Password = request.getParameter("DBPassword");
    String DataBase = request.getParameter("DBName");
```

I want to get the Values that has been entered to the text field,
 any ideas ?

Comment: You're thinking about sending a password in plain text over HTTP?  That's not a good design, either.

Comment: its  just an example i could write text1 text2 and text3 the security is not an issue here

Comment: @Bozho i have 3 TextFields(Vaadin) the Fully qualified names are "DBName" , "DBUserName", and "DBPassword"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code almost looks finished. I only edited it a little bit (I wasn't sure what your actual problem was). You could simply use java's built in support for [posting data](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/Post.html). You can read more about querystrings in [the vaadin book.](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.httpservletrequestlistener.html)

```
    TextField DBName;
    TextField DBUserName;
    TextField DBPassword;

    DBName = new TextField("Enter DB Name");
    DBName.setColumns(20);
    DBUserName = new TextField("Enter UserName");
    DBUserName.setColumns(20);
    DBPassword = new TextField("Enter Password");
    DBPassword.setColumns(20);

    Button b = new Button("Connect");
    b.setImmediate(true);
    b.addListener(new ClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            // post form values using java url connection


        }
    })
```